# react-navigation: connect with component/screen without props/state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigationbar, react-props

I'm looking for a way to connect the headerLeft and headerRight buttons of react-navigation with the screen/component it should be showed on, without using the props/state of that component.

We moved all our navigation transitions to one single service (at first because we needed it outside our react-components, but decided to replace it app-wide to keep one consistent flow).

Now, besides this service, we have few header-buttons, of which 2 require interaction with the screen: a cancel/finish and an edit button... Ideally, they would have a a simple callback which can be provided in the Component.

As suggested in the docs, this is the one class we use as a service:

```
import {StackActions, NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import type {NavigationRoute, NavigationParams} from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName: string, params?: NavigationParams) {
  _navigator.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName, params}));
}

function reset(routeName: string, params?: NavigationParams) {
  //...
}

function getCurrentRoute(): NavigationRoute | undefined {
  //...
}

function goBack() {
  _navigator._navigation.goBack();
}

function getCurrentParams() {
  return _navigator.state.params || {};
}

function setParams(params) {
  _navigator._navigation.setParams(params);
}

export default {
  //all functions
};
```

This is the button we have:

```
FinishCancelButton = () => (
  <Button onPress={() => NavigationService.getCurrentParams().canFinish ? NavigationService.setParams({finish: true}) : NavigationService.setParams({cancel: true})}>
    <Text>
      {NavigationService.getCurrentParams().canFinish ? 'finish' : 'cancel'}
    </Text>
  </Button>
),
```

Before, the navigation object of the state of the component was passed, which would trigger state changes (canFinish from the component and pushback finish/cancel) and with `componentWillReceiveProps` (which is deprecated now) it updated the screen. But now this connection is gone, and we're looking for way to connect the two...

Ideally this would be a a simple callback:

```
FinishCancelButton = (onFinish) => (<Button onPress={onFinish} ... />)
```

But I don't see a way to do this. An other possible solution I've thought of is to attach a listener from the component to the service: which notifies when a certain property is changed.

Is there a way to create the button in the component itself, which can access the state?

Does anyone have any idea? Or if you have some more questions or other approaches, please share!